# Windows 8.1 - I need to run everything "as administrator" for things to work properly

Tags: windows, uac

suddenly everything I launch needs to be administrator or it won't work.

Including all installers, if I launch an installer without right clicking and selecting administrator, it won't work.

What can I do to make it normal?

Even my dropbox won't start with windows because it says it has no permission, requiring me to launch it as administrator.

Comment: Have you tried loading a System Restore point?

Comment: I think it's attached to my microsoft account, use to be that way before formatting, I just formatted it and it's still the same.

Comment: Was this local account a User or Administrator when you linked it to the Microsoft account?